# If $(\alpha_t)$ is $\mathbb{F}^X$-progressive for a continuous process $(X_t)$, can we write $\alpha_t = \tilde{\alpha}(t,X)$?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, stochastic-filtering

Let $X = (X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a continuous, real-valued process defined on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, and let $\mathbb{F}^X = (\mathcal{F}_{t}^X)_{t \geq 0}$ be the filtration generated by $X$. Suppose that $\alpha = (\alpha_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is real-valued and $\mathbb{F}^X$-progressive. Can we write

- $\alpha_t(\omega) = \tilde{\alpha}(t,X(\omega))$ for some product measurable function $\tilde{\alpha} : \mathbb{R}_+ \times C(\mathbb{R}_+;\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

***or***

- $\alpha_t(\omega) = \tilde{\alpha}(t,X_{t \land \cdot}(\omega))$ for some product measurable function $\tilde{\alpha} : \mathbb{R}_+ \times C(\mathbb{R}_+;\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ?

Here $C(\mathbb{R}_+;\mathbb{R})$ denotes the space of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}_+$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

The answer does not seem to be a simple application of the [Doob-Dynkin factorization lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%E2%80%93Dynkin_lemma) + [functional monotone class argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem) as the progressive $\sigma$-algebra (from my understanding) is not generated by a random variable nor does it have "nice" elementary generators.

Comment: Here $X(\omega)$ stands for the function $t \mapsto X_t(\omega)$ ?

Comment: @rubikscube09 yes, exactly.